# Angular2 not loading when directly browsed to route address or on refresh

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

In the application there is a route defined:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: MainComponent },
  { path: 'users', component: UsersComponent }
]
```

In index.html the base href is also correctly defined.

```
<base href="/">
```

When navigating through application the routes are loaded correctly.
But when users enters `.../users` directly through the browser the application is not loaded and returns 404. Also when the users refresh the webpage (F5), the application is also not loaded.

Is there something wrong with angular code or server configuration?

Comment: what do you mean by When navigating through application the routes are loaded correctly. ?

Comment: You might be looking for something [like this](https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed/wiki/Deploying-prod-build-to-Apache-2). What's your server config?

Comment: Thanks for example!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your server setup. 
You need to either set up a redirect to `index.html` for when a 404 occurs,

Or set up a rewrite so that every request after a certain path always leads to `index.html`,

Or simply change the location strategy to hash instead of HTML5 (although not what I'd recommend for a few reasons, as Peter said).

Comment: Correct answer - but hash strategy is not recommended - since it takes away some of the possibilities with server side rendering (which is important for search engines etc.)