# Angular 7 <base href="./"> refresh page problems

Tags: angular, http-status-code-404, href, radix

In angular 7 when using `<base href="/">` and `ng build --prod` on terminal  , don't works on production server. If I use `<base href="./">` Works but when refresh it loose the path and I get 404

Comment: you shouldnt use `<base href=“./”>` in production, you should change it to your actual url/host name

Comment: I tried that. It opens and I can navigate with the menu. But when I refresh the page on some url that isn't the root I get 404

Comment: then it sounds like an issue with your host

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution here: 
[Angular deployment - 404 on page Refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45072185/angular-deployment-404-on-page-refresh?rq=1)

with -> import {LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy} from '@angular/common';

using >ng build --prod --base-href=/my/app/

It adds an # in the url but works fine and I can refresh the page.

Thanks